# Javascript form - field not required

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form (a vehicle filter) with fields: made, model and year. All fields are required, but I want "year" filed not to be required to be optional. I deleted the line with alert "select year" but I'm stuck. I tried to make changes to the enableYear function but nothing. I just want the "year" field to be optional. When I choose "make - audi" and "model - A4", without choosing "year" and hit search button the form to display all the products for Audi A4.

A lot of thanks in advance! I hope you understand me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getModel(obj){
        jQuery('#ajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "admin/utility/getSearchModel.php?mId=" + obj.value,
        success: function(msg){
                jQuery('#ajaxloader').hide();
                jQuery('#model').html("");
                jQuery('#model').html(msg);
                if(obj.value > 0){
                    jQuery('#model').prop('disabled', false);
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('#model').prop('disabled', true);
                    jQuery('#year').val(-1);
                    jQuery('#year').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function enableYear(obj){
        if(obj.value == -1){
            jQuery('#year').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#year').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }

    function validation(){
        if(jQuery('#make').val()=='-1'){
            alert("Select Make");
            return false;
        }
        else if(jQuery('#model').val()=='-1'){
            alert("Select Model");
            return false;
        }
        else if(jQuery('#year').val()=='-1'){
                    alert("Select Year");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            gotoSearch();
        }

    }

function gotoSearch(){
    var syear = jQuery('#year').val();
    var smake = jQuery('#make').val();
    smodel = jQuery('#model').val();
    window.location = "index.php?route=makemodel/makemodel&syear=" + syear + "&make=" + smake + "&model=" + smodel;
}
</script>
```

Comment: According to your profile, you asked a question earlier this month, received an answer that you acknowledged in the comments was helpful, but didn't mark the answer as correct. If you're going to ask for help, but not reward the people who help you by giving them the "correct answer" points, you're going to find that few people are willing to help. I didn't try to answer your question for this reason, but I see that someone did. You should (1) mark this person's answer correct if it helps you and (2) go back to your earlier question and mark an answer correct there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation function will be like this:

```
function validation(){
    if(jQuery('#make').val()=='-1'){
        alert("Select Make");
        return false;
    }
    else if(jQuery('#model').val()=='-1'){
        alert("Select Model");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        gotoSearch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works perfect. And thanks for telling me about the "correct answer" points.